# TypeORM initialize new database using migrations

Tags: mysql, database-migration, typeorm

How is it possible to initialize a new database with TypeORM?
When using `typeorm schema:sync` the schema gets generated, but the migrations table is missing.
 So if I have a newer migration now, typeorm will try to apply the older migrations aswell, which of course does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't use `schema:sync` at all.

always use `migration:generate` and `migration:run` to modify schema, including the first creation.

when you need create a completely new db, just run all the migrations.

Comment: I totally forgot this question. This is the correct answer!